# logout from facebook generating error

Tags: android, facebook

in my application, I can easily login but when ever I click on logout button, it gives me an error

I want when I click on logout button,and after that I click on login button,I get the same dialog box appear for login that ask for emailid and the password.but when I click on login button after logout, it only show me the toast displaying you are already login.

**MainActivity**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        Facebook fb;
    Button login,getData,logout;    
    ImageView ig;
    String app_id;
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;

    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
      app_id= getString(R.string.app_id);
      fb= new Facebook(app_id);
      login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
      logout=(Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
      getData=(Button) findViewById(R.id.getData);
      // ig= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
      login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginToFacebook();
        }
        });


    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(fb.isSessionValid()){
            logoutFromFacebook();
        }
    }
    });
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(fb);

        }


        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void loginToFacebook() {

            mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
            long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

            if (access_token != null) {
                fb.setAccessToken(access_token);

                login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // Making get profile button visible
                getData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + fb.isSessionValid());
            }

            if (expires != 0) {
                fb.setAccessExpires(expires);
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "already login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //logoutFromFacebook();
            }

            if (!fb.isSessionValid()) {
                fb.authorize(this,
                        new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                        new DialogListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {
                                // Function to handle cancel event
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                // Function to handle complete event
                                // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                             editor = mPrefs.edit();
                                editor.putString("access_token",
                                        fb.getAccessToken());
                                editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                        fb.getAccessExpires());
                                editor.commit();

                                // Making Login button invisible
                                login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                // Making logout Button visible
                                getData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(DialogError error) {
                                // Function to handle error
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                                // Function to handle Facebook errors
                            }
                        });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void logoutFromFacebook() {
            mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                    Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
                    if (Session.getActiveSession() != null) {
                        //editor.remove("access_token");
                        mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.clear();
                        editor.commit();
                        Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation(); 
                        } Session.setActiveSession(null); 
                }

                @Override
                public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                        Object state) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                        Object state) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**logcat**

```
04-17 11:05:53.375: E/AndroidRuntime(12371): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1443
04-17 11:05:53.375: E/AndroidRuntime(12371): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid context argument
04-17 11:05:53.375: E/AndroidRuntime(12371):    at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.createInstance(CookieSyncManager.java:86)
04-17 11:05:53.375: E/AndroidRuntime(12371):    at com.facebook.internal.Utility.clearCookiesForDomain(Utility.java:286)
04-17 11:05:53.375: E/AndroidRuntime(12371):    at com.facebook.internal.Utility.clearFacebookCookies(Utility.java:310)
04-17 11:05:53.375: E/AndroidRuntime(12371):    at com.facebook.Session.closeAndClearTokenInformation(Session.java:614)
04-17 11:05:53.375: E/AndroidRuntime(12371):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.logoutImpl(Facebook.java:665)
04-17 11:05:53.375: E/AndroidRuntime(12371):    at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$1.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:89)
```

**facebook.java**

```
@Deprecated
public String logout(Context context) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    return logoutImpl(context);
}

String logoutImpl(Context context) throws MalformedURLException, IOException  {
    checkUserSession("logout");
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("method", "auth.expireSession");
    String response = request(b);

    long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Session sessionToClose = null;

    synchronized (this.lock) {
        sessionToClose = session;

        session = null;
        accessToken = null;
        accessExpiresMillisecondsAfterEpoch = 0;
        lastAccessUpdateMillisecondsAfterEpoch = currentTimeMillis;
        sessionInvalidated = false;
    }

    if (sessionToClose != null) {
        sessionToClose.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }

    return response;
}
```

Comment: post your logcat also....i think you are doing some database operations on logout...

Comment: add try catch block to your code...it will let you know at which line number your are getting the exception...

Comment: now it is different exception...i don't see any database column related exception...

Comment: yes i change something now..,i tried to null the access_token and ecpires in logout methods,that's why it is showing this error now

Comment: Change your `Toast` context as `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "already login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: @  GrIsHu , sry but i donot get you,what will happen if i make changes in toast. ??

Comment: post the line which you are getting the exception

Comment: if possible post logoutImpl method..

Comment: @   Vamshi i post that too